# Confusion in concentration of P type

Tags: semiconductors, homework

[image]

Here as the acceptors atom are greater than the donars atom so the it must be P type. but for the 2nd part i am confused whether the concentration should i take the original concentration of boron (\$2*10^{16}\$) **OR** its should be \$N_a -N_d\$=\$2*10^{16}-10^{16}=10^{16}\$.can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting concentration is the difference \$N_a -N_d\$.

That's because the **one** acceptor atom plus **one** donor atom combine into **two** neutral atoms.

Since there is only **one** donor atom for each **two** acceptors, only **half** of the acceptors will combine with the donors.

The net result is that \$10^{16}/cm^3\$ will be left uncombined and those determine the resulting concentration.